# Do contacts synchronise with Gmail contact?

Tags: contacts, gmail

I have moved from Android to Windows Phone 7. I transferred all my contacts via Bluetooth and have added my Gmail account to the phone.

If I add/edit contacts will they be synchronised to my Gmail contact list? If not, is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, when you add a contact you are offered the option of what service to create the contact in, Gmail, Windows Live, etc.

**To create a new contact**

1. On Start, tap People.
2. Flick to All, and then tap New .
3. Tap New contact.
4. **Tap the account you want to create the contact in.**

Reference: [Windows Phone Help - How to add a contact](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-us/howto/wp7/people/create-edit-or-delete-a-contact.aspx)

If you edit a contact that is from your Gmail contacts, those changes will sync back to Gmail.

**To Manually Sync changes back to the cloud account**
If you don't want to wait for changes to automatically sync back to the account.

1. Navigate to Settings
2. System
3. email+accounts
4. Long press on the account and the option to sync is displayed.

Comment: Thanks seems to work. Initially thought it didn't as it takes a while for the changes to sync.

Comment: @row1 Great! I'm not sure of the sync schedule, but if you are testing it out, you can manually sync the account.  Go to settings > system > email+accounts and then long press on your Gmail account, it will give you an option to sync.

Comment: @jimueller you can add this info about manual sync to your answer. It should not remain only here, in little comment ;)

Comment: I believe the email sync schedule also applies to contacts. Don't quote me on it but if you set it to "as items arrive" it should be immediate, I believe.

Comment: I'm not sure @jimueller's answer is still correct. It used to work like that but I'm finding that it no longer does. Please see also [my question today](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2388/how-to-operate-a-separate-group-of-contacts-in-the-people-hub).