# Backup Contacts

Tags: contacts, htc, backup

I am trying to backup my contacts for my HTC Arrive.  The phone is getting replaced because the USB port is no longer working.  I tried syncing my contacts to my hotmail account, but it is not giving me an option to sync my contacts.  I created a gMail account, and told it to sync my contacts with that account, but when I logged into the gMail account, I did not see any contacts. Does anyone have any advice for me?

Thank you,
CampSoup1988

PS: I understand that currently there is no way to back up text messages unless the phone is rooted?

**UPDATE:** I just re-added my hotmail account, and it gave me the option to sync my contacts, but when I logged into my hotmail account, I did not see any contacts.

**UPDATE:** ***SOLVED!!*** While on the phone with HTC tech support, the technician explained to me that even though the sync for the Live account only gives the option to sync email, behind the scenes, they also sync your contacts, and according to HTC, you could only sync your contacts to a Live account

Answer (score 1):

You can sync your contact to other account e.g. gmail. This [answer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/429/295) explains how to do so.