# Can the calendar get dates from the people hub?

Tags: 8.0, calendars, people-hub

Is there any way in WP8 to easily get the birthdays and anniversaries you've entered in the people hub into the calendar app without having to type them in again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am on WP 7, but this should be only incidental. If it is an option, you could [synchronise your contacts to your LIVE account](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1142/backup-contacts) and create an [outlook.com](http://www.outlook.com)-Account (you don't have to use it for e-mail). There you should get an birthday-calendar for your contacts automatically. It should also sync with your contacts, whenever you edit or add a new contact.

You can import this calendar by synchronizing your phone with the outlook account. Then you can enable it from the *Settings*-menu in the calendar hub.

Hope this helps!

Comment: yup, if you have contacts in a microsoft account with birthdays, you can turn on a birthday calendar in the calendar settings. not sure if it works for google or yahoo.

Comment: afaik all your contacts should be synced with your MS-Account behind the scenes, automatically, even if they are actually Google or Yahoo-Accounts.

Comment: I think that is only true for Twitter and Facebook, since you set up syncing for them via the web interface. Google/yahoo/etc are set up client side. May have changed with the new contacts site though.