# How do I sync contacts between email accounts?

Tags: sync, contacts

How can I get contacts from one email account to sync to another email account?

Comment: Hi, I have edited out the first part of your question as it is covered here http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/428/do-contacts-synchronise-with-gmail-contact?rq=1

Comment: Not sure if that belongs to WindowsPhone site...

Comment: Maybe you can confirm what you want to accomplish? I assume that you want your contacts to sync to your Gmail account and also sync to another email account of your choice?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this feature exist. It's not hard yet not trival to know the sync direction: from google to yahoo or vice versa.

For me using the built in import / saving to CSV (good backup) is the easy choise, (It does not keep my contact updated).

I thing that for ongoing sync someone will have to create an app and even then you will need to run it manually.

Answer (score 1):

You don't, as you basically do not need to: all contact information from all connected accounts are shown in the single People Hub on your phone.

If you have a specific use case where you need to move/migrate/sync contact information between different accounts or account types, you will need to look to a third party software solution that will enable you to do this.