# How to keep a separate group of contacts in the People Hub?

Tags: contacts, gmail, people-hub, microsoft-account

I've spent hours searching the forums and getting lost in blog articles relating to Microsoft and Google getting into sync fights and support for this and that being "[withdrawn](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/how-to/wp7/people/sync-google-email-contacts-and-calendars-faq)", then "extended".

Let me explain my problem.

I'm involved in running a sports club which means every September we enroll new students and register a whole bunch of parent phone numbers.

I run my life stuff on Microsoft accounts, and the sports club on Gmail/Google Contacts. Last year this worked perfectly. After taking enrollments I data inputted 50 students details into Gmail Contacts, and they showed up on my phone automatically as Google contacts. During school year when a parent calls or messages, I can instantly see who we're talking about. At the end of the year I could drop the entire list in one go, and didn't need to weed through my personal contacts. In other words they remained separate from my personal contacts but fully part of People Hub for phone calls and messaging. Perfect.

This year, it seems because I've updated to 7.8 and/or had to reset my phone I seem to have lost Google sync. So no students/parents showing on my phone even though I've data inputted them all in Google.

There does seem to be an app/product called [gsync](http://blog.rushabhgosar.com/blog/2013/05/01/now-sync-google-contacts-on-windows-phone-7-8/) but it seems to offer "importing Google contacts into People Hub". I don't want these students imported or merged with my Microsoft account because at the end of the year I want to drop them all again as an entire group.

In fact, I don't need to use Google Contacts at all - it was always just a mechanism to maintain separateness. If the Microsoft account offers the ability to import an entire CSV of contacts as a distinct group and drop them again a year later (without having to pick through them one by one) then that would be fine. But I can't see a way to do that.

I don't even need "synching". I don't update these enrollment details once I have them. But I do need separateness.

Can anyone offer a solution? Preferably getting Google Contacts to sync because that's what I'm familiar with, or else any other solution which allows me to operate a defined subgroup in People Hub which can be imported and removed en masse.

Comment: Did you try the solution here: http://tizianocacioppolini.blogspot.com/2013/04/windows-phone-78-gmail-sync-contacts.html#.Ukh43YZi3ex

Comment: @HaLaBi i absolutely did see that post and tried it! like i said i've been looking a long time at this problem. it didn't work. i can't remember now, it either errored or it simply didnt bring the contacts across from google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to delete all contacts on a group in people hub at once. I have an idea that will definitely work. Create a new Hotmail/live email, add your work contacts there. Now whenever you want to delete all contacts at once, login to the website version of people hub and select one contact then press `ctrl + A` and then click Delete. This way you will have the separation you asked for and a way to delete all contacts at once.

Comment: just tried it! works! so simple it didnt occur to me to add more _Microsoft_ accounts!